# Dynamic jsPlumb connections are not drawing an accurate line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I am using jsPlumb to draw a connection line from one image to another image but the line is not accurate. I am drawing a line between the two images when the user holds left mouse button on the source image and releases the left mouse button on the destination image. I am passing the correct image ids and the line is being drawn but the line does not connect the two images.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here my code:

```
$(document).on("mousedown",".component", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 3)
    {
        source = e.target.id;
    }
}).on("mouseup", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 3)
    {
        destination = e.target.id;
        alert("src: " + source + " dest: " + destination);
        jsPlumb.connect({ source:source, target:destination });
    }
});
```

The two images (start and end) are being dynamically created. Also they are using the jquery ui draggable and droppable.

But the two ids are being passed correctly.

Here is the rendered html:

```
<div id="circuit-board" style="width:100%; height:400px; background-color:#333; color:white;" class="ui-droppable"><div class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><img id="component_1" class="component ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle canvas-element jsplumb-endpoint-anchor jsplumb-connected" src="images/components/start.png" width="100" height="100" style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;"><div class="jsplumb-endpoint jsplumb-endpoint-anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 20px; left: 45px; top: 95px;"><svg style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px" width="20" height="20" pointer-events="all" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" fill="#456" stroke="none" style=""></circle></svg></div><div class="jsplumb-endpoint jsplumb-endpoint-anchor jsplumb-draggable jsplumb-droppable" style="position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 20px; left: 1119px; top: 395px;"><svg style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px" width="20" height="20" pointer-events="all" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" fill="#456" stroke="none" style=""></circle></svg></div><svg style="position:absolute;left:49px;top:99px" width="1086" height="462" pointer-events="none" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="jsplumb-connector"><path d="M 1074 300 C 1064 450 10 150 0 0 " transform="translate(6,6)" pointer-events="visibleStroke" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" fill="none" stroke="#456" style="" stroke-width="4"></path></svg></div><div class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; left: 402px; top: 0px;"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div><img id="component_2" class="component ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle canvas-element jsplumb-endpoint-anchor jsplumb-connected" src="images/components/end.png" width="100" height="100" style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div></div>
```

The source id = component_1 and the destination id = component_2.

If there is a better way to go about doing this....i am all ears. thanks!

Comment: What version of JSPlumb are you using?

Comment: I am using JSPlumb 2.0.7-min.js

Comment: I am confused how the app works. If you're using jQuery drag and drop on the images, doesn't the source image move with your mouse as you drag to the second image? So how do you mouse-up on the second image? Can you maybe post your full example to jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell in your example what's going on, because you don't provide the full code. However, I'm guessing that you're dragging the elements around (you mentioned you're using jQuery drag and drop), and that jsPlumb is failing to recognize that the elements have moved.

If that's the case, then it's because jsPlumb caches the element offsets for performance reasons, so you need to tell jsPlumb to explicitly [recalculate the offsets](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_recalculateOffsets).

My guess is that something like this would work for you:

```
on("mouseup", function (e) {
  if (e.which == 3)
  {
    jsPlumb.recalculateOffsets($("#circuit-board>div"));
    destination = e.target.id;
    jsPlumb.connect({ source:source, target:destination });
  }
});
```

I'm not certain exactly on what element to call `recalculateOffsets` on, in general it should be the parent of the draggable components.